# Can't run Ubuntu WSL on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server

I tried running Ubuntu 1804 via WSL on a Windows Server 2019 machine but I am having trouble:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu> .\ubuntu1804.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

It seems like Windows cannot find something that ubuntu1804.exe wants to do.

I am in the right directory:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        4/14/2019  11:03 AM                AppxMetadata
d-----        4/14/2019  11:03 AM                Assets
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM         212438 AppxBlockMap.xml
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM           3835 AppxManifest.xml
------        8/17/2018   3:17 AM          11112 AppxSignature.p7x
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM      223983209 install.tar.gz
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM           5400 resources.pri
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM         211968 ubuntu1804.exe
------        8/17/2018   3:15 AM            744 [Content_Types].xml
```

I followed these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

I also did:

```
$userenv = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $userenv + "C:\Users\Administrator\Ubuntu", "User")
```

Comment: Is that distro installed? Does `wsl.exe` or `bash.exe` work?

Comment: Same errors: ```PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> bash
The system cannot find the path specified.
PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> wsl
The system cannot find the path specified.```

Comment: Try to add the distro path into Path (system variable) and run wslconfig.exe /u Ubuntu-XX.XX. Run the distro's exe (ubuntu1804.exe).

It works for me.